# Displaying the value of a variable within a multi line print python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print out a multi line statement and have variables be displayed within the print. My code is looks as follows:

```
snacks = ['twix','twix','twix','twix']

t = snacks.count('twix')

def stock(x):
    print('''

    Snack    Stock
    -------------
    Twix:     x

''')
```

I want the value of t to show where I put the variable into the multi-line print where calling

```
stock(t)
```

Gives me:

```
    Snack    Stock
    -------------
    Twix       4
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look at the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.format) function, e.g `print('Twix: {}'.format(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
snacks = ['twix','twix','twix','twix']

t = snacks.count('twix')

def stock(x):
    print("Snack    Stock")
    print("-------------")
    print("Twix:     %d"% (t))

stock(t)
```

Comment: Awesome, this does work. Just curious though if there is an option to what I was trying to do originally? Because I have 6 other items in the list that I also want the stock shown for so I was hoping to avoid having to write a print for every line. Also, it'd be good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can print `\n` to print new line,and use `str.format` to format your string:

> '<'  Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space
>   '>'  Forces the field to be right-aligned within the available space
>   '^'  Forces the field to be centered within the available space.

```
snacks = ['twix','test','twix','example']

t = snacks.count('twix')
print("Snack    Stock    \n-------------")

from collections import Counter
for k,v in Counter(snacks).items():
    print('{:<9}    {:<9}'.format(k,v))
```

Output:

```
Snack    Stock    
-------------
test         1        
twix         2        
example      1
```

See more details from [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Hope this helps.